# asp.net vb How to select a Listbox item if it matches a specific string?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listbox, listboxitem

I have three Listboxes DivisionListbox, SitesListBox and StoresListBox.

1. The DivisionListbox contains multiple store franchises with the
   text being division number and the store name, the value is the
   division number. **(Ex. Text = "1-BestBuy" and Value 1)**
2. The SitesListbox contains the store number, store name and the
   division number as text and the value is the store number. **(Ex. Text
   = 103 - BestBuy [ 1 ], Value 103)**
3. The StoreListbox is empty until you pass the SitesListbox items.
   Once it has items i take the store number values to perform a query.

The purpose of the DivisionListbox is to select an franchise to select all the items in the SitesLisbox that belong to that franshise.

How can i select all the items in the SitesListbox where the text inside the square brackets matches the the selected value in the DivisionListbox.?

Originally i had the DivisionListbox and SitesListbox value as the division number but the problem in the SitesListbox is that is since multiple items share the same value it messes with the single item selection.

**Current Code**

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    DivisionSelection()

End Sub

Private Sub DivisionSelection()

    SitesListBox.SelectionMode = ListSelectionMode.Multiple
    If DivisionListBox.SelectedValue IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each item As ListItem In SitesListBox.Items
            If item.Value = DivisionListBox.SelectedValue Then
                item.Selected = True
            End If
        Next
    End If

End Sub

Protected Sub SiteButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SiteButton.Click

    SitesListBox.SelectionMode = ListSelectionMode.Multiple
    While SitesListBox.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing
        StoresListBox.Items.Add(SitesListBox.SelectedItem)
        SitesListBox.Items.Remove(SitesListBox.SelectedItem)
    End While
    SitesListBox.ClearSelection()


End Sub

Protected Sub StoreButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles StoreButton.Click


    StoresListBox.SelectionMode = ListSelectionMode.Multiple
    While StoresListBox.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing
        SitesListBox.Items.Add(StoresListBox.SelectedItem)
        StoresListBox.Items.Remove(StoresListBox.SelectedItem)
    End While
    StoresListBox.ClearSelection()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figured it out by using this method.

```
 If DivisionListBox.SelectedValue IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim selected As String = DivisionListBox.SelectedValue
        selected = "[ " + selected + " ]"
        Label1.Text = selected
        For Each item As ListItem In SitesListBox.Items
            If item.Text.Contains(selected) Then
                item.Selected = True
            End If
        Next
    End If
```